# chat system - how to send data in this code - php ,ajax ,js

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a problem when sending data using Ajax

`t_id` This is the variable I am trying to send to the chat.php using ajax.

```js
function tid() {
  var t_id = "<?php echo $AC["id"]; ?>";
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax/chat.php',
    data: 't_id=' + t_id
  });
}

function ajax() {

  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

  req.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById('chat').innerHTML = req.responseText;
    }
  }
  req.open('GET', 'ajax/chat.php', true);
  req.send();

}
setInterval(function() {
  ajax()
}, 1000);
setInterval(function() {
  tid()
}, 1000);
```

`chat.php` page code

```
    <?php
include("../INC/header.php");
function formatDate($date){
    return date('g:i a', strtotime($date));
}
$path = ""; include("../INC/emo.php");
$t_id = $_POST["t_id"];
$query = "SELECT * FROM chat WHERE f_id='$UID' AND t_id='$t_id' OR f_id='$t_id' AND t_id='$UID' ORDER BY msg_data DESC"; $run = $CONFIG->query($query);
while($row = $run->fetch_array()) : 
$r_id = $row["f_id"];
$t_id = $row["t_id"];
$r_s = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE id='$r_id' "; $r_q = mysqli_query($CONFIG, $r_s); $r_i = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r_q); ?>
<div id="chat_data" class="text-right">
    <span class="btn <? if($r_id == $UID){echo"btn-info";}else{echo"btn-secondary";} ?>"><img width="45" style="border-radius:100%;" src="IMG/<?php echo $r_i['img_i']; ?>"></span> :
    <span style="<? if($r_id == $UID){echo"color:green;";} ?>text-align:right;"><?php echo $msg = str_replace($EMO_1,$EMO_2,$row["msg"]); ?></span>
    <span style="float:left;"><?php echo formatDate($row['msg_data']); ?></span>
</div><hr>
<? endwhile; ?>
```

The problem now is that the `function ajax()` is sent and then the `function tid()` is sent. I want to send all at the same time instead of sending one by one

Comment: Where is the issue?  What exactly works and what doesn't?  Have you researched other existing pages that discuss rolling your own chat system?  You need to isolate your problem and make your question clear.

Comment: The issue is that I am trying to send the variable `t_id` to a page `chat.php`

Comment: And what is the expected and ACTUAL result? Errors in console, PHP errors? Please read [ask]

Comment: Why are you mixing jQuery and XMLHttpRequest ? Use EITHER and do not use XMLHttpRequest if you need jQuery anyway

Comment: I'm not good at JS, and this is a code from the internet to add chat system to my website ,I'm just trying to send this variable `t_id`

Comment: But does not work that way Is there a solution ?

Comment: "It does not work that way" is telling us nothing about how you expect it to work - what does the server do? You need to store the messages and read them back

Comment: what exectly not working? your ajax call seems to be ok(only missing success function) but I dont think that the reason its not working.
try to show us the chat.php page.
and also try to use the success + error function to see what you get.
we also gonna need to know if u get some errors.

Comment: https://www.google.nl/search?q=jquery+php+chat

Comment: I have updated the code above, now you see that the chat page depends on the variable `t_id` sent to it.

Comment: The story doesn't seem to be improving.  Your query is insecure because you are passing user-supplied data directly in your query.  You are mixing object-oriented and procedural mysqli syntax.  Pick one or the other.  You don't need `formatDate`, you can format the datetime stamp in your SELECT clause.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean ?

Comment: Your query could benefit from some parentheses in the WHERE clause.

Comment: What file is the first snippet in?  `tid()` is sending `$_POST` data and `ajax()` is sending `$_GET` data.

Comment: I'm not good at JS, and this is a code from the internet to add chat system to my website.

Comment: The loop needs to be this, and this only: `var t_id = "<?php echo $AC["id"]; ?>"; function getData() {
  $.post("ajax/chat.php", {"t_id" : t_id },function(data) { $("#chat").html(data)}); setTimeout(getData,1000); }`